# Где ошибка в моем коде к заданию?

Tags: python

**Задание:**

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет максимальное число, кратное 5. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 5.

**Мое решение:**

```
n=int(input())
b=0
for i in range (n):
   s=int(input())
   if s%5==0 and s>b:
        b=s
print(b)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: @andreymal так как у меня выводило в результате "0"

Comment: В каком результате? Что нам нужно сделать, чтобы тоже получить "0"?

Comment: я ввел так:
3
10
25
12

должно вывести 25 ,а выводит 0

Comment: Неправда, этот код выводит именно 25 как и должно https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YUHh.png

Comment: вот переписал : 
s=int(input())
result=[]
for i in range(s):
    n=int(input())
    if n%5==0:
        result.append(n)
print(max(result))

Comment: @andreymal у меня почему то в IDLE python не выводит)

Comment: Запустил в IDLE, тоже выводится 25 как и должно https://i.stack.imgur.com/j885V.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inp = input("> ").split(" ")
integers = [int(i) for i in inp]
result = []
for i in integers:
    if i%5 == 0:
        result.append(i)

print(max(result))
```

Comment: А где ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @andreymal Ответ на вопрос: "ваша программа вообще делает не то, что требуется (по этому о каких ошибках может идти речь)". Я решил еe переписать.

Comment: Программа делает то что требуется, перечитайте вопрос и код внимательнее

Comment: @andreymal А... точно. Я думал, зачем она изначально принимает длину(не внимательно прочитал). Но тогда в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica да все)я просто запутался и не мог понять почему код не работал вот и спросил)спасибо за помощь